# Is it possible to bypass a Router's MAC filtering by relaying to another Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I forgot my Router's admin password (the default was changed), and cannot reset it because currently I don't have access to the PPPoE username/password. **It seems** that my router is blocking one of my devices by MAC filtering. So I took an airport express, plugged it into the original router using LAN, and created a new network to use on my blocked device. sadly, the problem persisted. Is it possible that my Router can block my device, even if it's connected through my airport express? Or the problem isn't actually that my device is being blocked? (I've tried connecting my device to the Internet using my phone's hotspot, and it worked, so most probably, my device isn't the problem).

PS, the device is a Nintendo Switch, and it's giving me the error code: 2110-3128. It connects to the router, but cannot connect to the Internet, and disconnects automatically from the Wi-Fi.

Comment: "Is it possible that my Router can block my device, even if it's connected through my airport express?" - If you are talking about the configuration page then that is indeed possible.  If that isn't what you mean then your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my Google-fu is correct, An airport expres appears to act as an AP or AP client, which means it won't change the Mac address, it simply passes frames (which includes Mac address) between media.

In order to bypass a MAC filter, insert a router between your device and the target router. This will forward IP packets, but will rewrite the MAC address to the interface the packet leaves the router on. (For PCs there are other ways that don't require hardware, I'd imagine a Nintendo would be a lot harder to spoof)